# is it possible to update many rows in single script?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqladmin

[enter image description here][1]idk how i can make this script, im working with my `oms`database with inserted employee data and  i wanted to update every single employees data based on their team. which means if 3 employees are in Team-A i need to update all of them then save at once.
I use `SELECT` to view all this data then use this `UPDATE` codes.

```
UPDATE `oms`        
        SET 
        `EmployeeNumber` = :EmployeeNumber,
        `EmployeeName` = :EmployeeName,
        `SectionName` = :SectionName,
        `TeamName` = :TeamName,
        `monthname` = :monthname,
        `Date` = :Date,
        `D01` = :D01,
        `D02` = :D02,
        `D03` = :D03,
WHERE
`id` = :id AND
`TeamName` = 'Denki Customer Support'
```

The first row is updating but the next is not.
I think there's a `while/loop` need to be done or `if/else` condition, I'm not sure.

here's i want to be as a result.
thanks for helping me guys :)

Comment: The SQL statement updates whichever rows match the specified `WHERE` clause. So...if you want to update all rows in one particular team, specify that but *don't* specify other criteria like ID. Except...you don't want to run the `UPDATE` statement shown against the whole team, because it sets the employee names and numbers, and presumably you don't want everybody to have the same name...

Comment: probably updates 1 at a time because of `\`id\` = :id`. That is if ids are unique to a single employee

Comment: you can, with `CASE`, but i would be inclined to just loop it

Comment: @nnnnnn oh, cause i use `id` and `TeamName` to more specific so that it will update on their own `id`. So is not possible update the column of D01, D02, D03 with 3 employees at once?

Comment: I already said it is possible. `UPDATE [tablename] SET [a list of fields to be updated and their new values] WHERE [whatever criteria]`. So in the `UPDATE` statement in the question, remove the ID from the `WHERE`, and remove the fields that don't need to be updated, keeping just the `D01`, etc.

Comment: @nnnnnn super thanks i got it but i still have concern coz column of `D01` will be as one value which i wanted to be different based in `id`.

Answer (score -1):

You can update your teams data by simply using `TeamName` = 'teamName' only. It will update all the rows with that teamName.

If you will use ID and teamName, then it will not work.

Hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: thanks i got it! But as you said it will not work if use this two? i will edit and add image for my question to be more accurate.